# How can I calculate the relative velocity on the surface of a planet that is both rotating and orbiting a star?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics, relative-motion

So here is the problem that I'm dealing with:

[image: Physics Problem]

I thought that I could just subtract the 10000 m/s from the 30000 m/s since they're spinning opposite of each other but that didn't end up giving me the right answer and was off by quite a bit. My questions are: In layman terms, what is this question asking? Why was my thought process incorrect? and finally, how can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the final sentence of the question says

> The red arrow points to a spot on the planet that faces in the -x direction.

At this point on the surface of the planet the velocity vector due to the planet’s rotation points in the -y direction (i.e. downwards in the diagram). You need to add this velocity *as a vector* to the planet’s orbital velocity vector.

You cannot just subtract one speed from the other because the two velocity vectors do not point in opposite directions.